# CreateFileA fails with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE error for Read Text FIle

Tags: file, winapi

I am trying to read a simple text file in Win32 app. But I am getting INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE error in the following code

```
void Avatar::readData(LPCSTR filename)
{
    LPVOID data[4096] = {};
    HANDLE hFile;
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)filename, L"File", MB_OK);
    hFile = CreateFileA(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to CreateFile - 'hFile'", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
    }

    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, &fileSize);
    DWORD read = -1;
    if (!ReadFile(hFile, static_cast< LPVOID >(&data), 4096, &read, NULL))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to ReadFile - 'hFile'", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Did you try [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)? Also what is in `filename`? You cannot just cast `LPCSTR` to `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: Casting an LPCSTR to a LPCWSTR in MessageBox() call makes me cringe a little. I suggest you comment this line and see if the behavior is still the same. Apart of that that there can be tons of reasons why it is failing, such as your user account, the path you try to access, ... All that aside, GetLastError() might help as mentioned before. Instead of the message box I recommend to check the path for correctness in debugger.

Comment: I'd also recommend that, if you've found an error condition (and reported it to the user/logged it/etc) that you shouldn't just then carry on in this method as if the handle is valid. I'd expect a `return` inside those error paths.